# Add CSS to multiple html files

Tags: html, css, file, addition

I have many html files, all named index.html but being in different subdirectories.
These files are created by a software. After these files being created, I want to add a Stylesheet to all of them!

If i use SEARCH:`"<head>"` and REPLACE:`"<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='/style.css'>"` it wouldnt work because the files would need relative paths.

Any idea how I could achieve my goal? While Iframes are oldschool they do not use the CSS of the main page i assume.

Other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an absolute path to your CSS-file. Then it doesn't matter that they're in different paths:

```
<link href="/styles/site.css" ...
```

Now every file will look up the `styles`-folder in the root, and the file `site.css` in that folder

Comment: OK. What I forgot to mention is that I am not using a webspace. The html file structure is only for a use on Harddrive and later on will be burned to CD-ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the absolute path as you mentioned.

And DO NOT open your html files directly in the

```
file://D:/path/to/your/file/index.html
```

because the root path '/' means D:/

You should setup a http server to host your pages and open them by visiting like

```
http://localhost/url/to/your/file/index.html
```

the root path '/' means

```
http://localhost/
```

Or upload them to a server.
In this way the absolute path of your css will work correctly.

Forget the relative paths.

Comment: As written above, I forgot to mention that I will edit the design locally on my harddrive and later on burn the whole thing to CD-ROM. So I would need different absolute paths while working on harddrive and using it on CD.

Comment: you can make the root path same-relatived to your html files. if you burn them on CD like `H:/abcd/index.html`, `H:/style/main.css`, when you developing you can host them like `http://localhost/abcd/index.html`, `http://localhost/style/main.css`, or you can just put your files under the root of one of your harddisk, like `C:/abcd/index.html`, `C:/style/main.css`, so you don't need different absolute paths.